# R-matrix for $SU(N)_k$ anyon model

Tags: topological-field-theory, topological-order, topological-phase

Does anyone know the $R$-move or $R$-matrix for $SU(N)_k$ anyon model? Thanks!
For the definition of $R$-move or $R$-matrix, please see the definition in Eq.(2.30) of this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.4206

(I searched the literature, and only found the result for $SU(2)_k$ case.)

Comment: Welcome on SE-Physics, as it stands your question is not helpful for any-one. Please make consistent question / provide references / ... In your case : what is a $R$-matrix, what is the $SU(N)_k$ anyon model ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To @FraSchelle: Sorry I am lazy to explain everything. The experts know what I said.

Comment: So I'm pretty sure experts knowing all the details about your questions are just around the corner IN YOUR LAB. If you use the website, please conform to the rules, which are the same as talking to any scholar in the next wing than yours : they do not know what you are talking about until you define it ! Thanks in advance, and enjoy using this Q&A platform

Comment: @FraSchelle, hi, thanks very much for your good suggestions. I will enrich the details soon.

Comment: I'm not an expert but I know this is a difficult question. I would recommend having a look at this article: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.5456v2.pdf they describe how one can fund the q-6j symbols and from these the R-symbols for rank 2 quantum groups.

Comment: Hi @Stackexchange_user23, it seems this reference is very helpful. I will read it soon. Thanks very much!